# Removing white space of urls with - in cakephp routing?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, routes, url-routing

I have a URL like `http://abc.com/users/index/University of Kansas` and i want to make it `University-of-Kansas`. How is it possible via mysql using Cakephp ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use the Cake built in `Inflector::slug($data, '-');`

Source: http://api.cakephp.org/class/inflector#method-Inflectorslug

So you would get the string "University of Kansas" from the `$this->params['url']`:

```
$data = $this->params['url'][....]:
$slug = Inflector::slug($data, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is being populated, but you probably want to store a tag, or slug field along with the full title. So your database would have both "University of Kansas" and also "University-of-Kansas" in a separate field. When you save an entry, you can auto-generate the latter field w/ a regex such as:

```
$slug = preg_replace("/[^-_0-9A-Za-z]/", "-", $title);
```

Depending on how your CakePHP is set up, you'd probably want to create a route that passed this slug value into the controller, so you could then look up the right entry in the database using that field.

Comment: It is much more useful to tell the person how to use Cake's built in tools for something like this.

Inflector::slug is the correct solution here.

Answer (score 0):

http://cake-syrup.sourceforge.net/ingredients/sluggable-behavior/

This is a behavior that allows your model to create slugs when records get saved or edited.